# Webpack not loading font from plugin in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, lightgallery, lightgallery-2

I'm new to Webpack and I'm trying to load the stylesheet of a plugin `lightgallery` installed through `yarn add`.

I can successfully load the JavaScript. However, the stylesheet crashes when trying to load a font:

`Error: Cannot find module '../fonts/lg.woff2?io9a6k'`

[image]

It gets loaded as follows:

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

`app/assets/javascript/packs/application.scss`:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "lightgallery/scss/lightgallery.scss";
```

Bootstrap loads fine.

In `lightgallery/scss/lightgallery.scss`:

```
@import 'lg-variables';
@import 'lg-mixins';
@import 'lg-fonts';
@import 'lg-theme-default';

// Core
@import 'lightgallery-core';
```

In `lightgallery/scss/_lg-fonts.scss`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'lg';
    src: url('#{$lg-path-fonts}/lg.woff2?io9a6k') format('woff2'),
        url('#{$lg-path-fonts}/lg.ttf?io9a6k') format('truetype'),
        url('#{$lg-path-fonts}/lg.woff?io9a6k') format('woff'),
        url('#{$lg-path-fonts}/lg.svg?io9a6k#lg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: block;
}
```

The folder `lightgallery/fonts` contains the files, not sure what the parameter `?io9a6k` is for

[image]

How can I get the stylesheets loading correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader/blob/v4-maintenance/packages/resolve-url-loader/README.md) to fix relative paths in SCSS:

```
yarn add resolve-url-loader
```

In `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/1039
// resolve-url-loader must be used before sass-loader
environment.loaders.get('sass').use.splice(-1, 0, {
  loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
});

const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = environment
```